# Loop on all servers using the lineinfile module

Tags: ansible

I wrote a playbook that does a series of tasks and at the end of the task execution, it puts the IP of the server where the task was executed along with the output of the task into a file.
Is it possible to change my task to run only when hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout is not equal to a certain value?

```
  - name: 
      lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: /tmp/grant.log
        line: >-
          {{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime() }}
          {{ item }}
          {{ hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout }}
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: You mean just like `when: hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout is not search('certainValue')` or `when: hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout != 'certainValue'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Is it possible to change my task to run only when `hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout` is not equal to a certain value?***

You mean just like `when: hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout is not search('certainValue')` or `when: hostvars[item].results_grant.stdout != 'certainValue'`?

Yes, of course. You may have a look into the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[item] }}"
    when: hostvars[item].ansible_system == 'Linux'
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Register the variable

```yaml
    - command: uname
      register: rg
```

and declare the dictionary of the hosts and the attribute *stdout*

```yaml
  hg: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
               zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                   map('extract', hostvars, ['rg', 'stdout'] ))) }}"
```

gives, for example

```yaml
  hg:
    test_11: FreeBSD
    test_13: FreeBSD
```

Now, you can iterate the dictionary and select the items. For example,

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: /tmp/grant.log
        line: >-
          {{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime() }}
          {{ item.key }}
          {{ item.value }}
      loop: "{{ hg|dict2items }}"
      when: item.value == 'FreeBSD'
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

created the below file on the controller

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/grant.log
2023-10-24 09:56:23 test_11 FreeBSD
2023-10-24 09:56:24 test_13 FreeBSD
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hg: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                 zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                     map('extract', hostvars, ['rg', 'stdout'] ))) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: uname
      register: rg

    - debug:
        var: hg
      run_once: true

    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: /tmp/grant.log
        line: >-
          {{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime() }}
          {{ item.key }}
          {{ item.value }}
      loop: "{{ hg|dict2items }}"
      when: item.value == 'FreeBSD'
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```